Error Due to Network Congestion
The GMT coin sent from the wallet section of the Stepn application to the spending section on March 31, 2024 was not received and remained suspended. Can you help me?
https://solscan.io/tx/59WBXyACmfSX6q5aG9q5WpKFWSxSCSoX5dzf2E2GAL1P3vrAsA4uqGbvPPbDn5UTCvKCHQUyZf5F4gV4yFEm4DRA

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
